# Unable to select (click) option in dropdown

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have a situation where I have to select 2 values from dropdowns (complex and object) before clicking a button to get a report. I am able to select a value in the first dropdown (complex) with no problem but when I try to select an option in the second dropdown (object) the same way it simply does not select the option and moves on to click the button. Here's a screenshot of the situation right before the script clicks the button. As you can see it has selected the correct option for the first dropdown and it looks like it found the correct option for the second dropdown but does not click it:

[image]

Here is the code I use to select adn click the first and second dropdown. The first dropdown is the first three lines. I then insert a wait in order to wait for a 'loading' popup to dissaper.
Then another three lines for the second dropdown that are pretty much the same as the first lines and another wait before clicking the button.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown1")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown1"))).selectByVisibleText("31H-135");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"1466\"]")).click(); //there are a lot of options here and the one I need is 1466
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);                 //3000 milliseconds is three second wait for loading popup.
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
driver.findElement(By.id("Dropdown2")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Dropdown2"))).selectByVisibleText("31H-135-01");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div[3]/span/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/select/option[2]")).click();
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);                 //3000 milliseconds is three second wait for loading popup.
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}

driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewer1_ctl04_ctl00")).click();   //view report button
```

Here's a bit of code for the first and second dropdown:

First dropdown:

```
<select id="Dropdown1" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; width: 127px;" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ReportViewer1$ctl04$ctl03$ddValue\',\'\')', 0)" name="ReportViewer1$ctl04$ctl03$ddValue">
<option value="1">02C-377</option>
<option value="2">02C-378</option>
<option value="3">02G-375</option>
<option value="4">02G-376</option>
<option value="5">03G-100</option>
<option value="6">03G-101</option>
<option value="7">03G-102</option>
<option value="8">03G-103</option>
<option value="9">03G-104</option>
```

etc

Second dropdown (values are based on first dropdown):

```
<select id="Dropdown2" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;" name="ReportViewer1$ctl04$ctl05$ddValue">
<option value="0" selected="selected"><Select a Value></option>
<option value="1">31H-135-01</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting by value or use absolute xpath for identifying the element.